# Python sorting 2D Array of tuples in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, tuples

I'm new to python and have an array, where each element is an array of tuples. I need to sort the tuples in the inner array by the first element in the tuple. My array looks something like this:

```
[[(u'10:30', u'11:20'), (u'08:30', u'09:20')], [(u'14:30', u'15:50'), (u'10:00', u'11:20'), (u'10:30', u'11:20'), (u'13:00', u'14:20')], [(u'10:30', u'11:20'), (u'08:30', u'09:20')], [(u'14:30', u'15:50'), (u'10:00', u'11:20'), (u'13:00', u'14:20')], [(u'10:30', u'11:20'), (u'08:30', u'09:20')]]
```

I tried doing something like

```
for index, elm in array:
    array[index] = sorted(elm, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

But I get the ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack. Not sure if my syntax is off or something

The expected result is

```
  [[ (u'08:30', u'09:20'), (u'10:30', u'11:20')], [ (u'10:00', u'11:20'), (u'10:30', u'11:20'), (u'13:00', u'14:20'), (u'14:30', u'15:50')], [(u'08:30', u'09:20'),(u'10:30', u'11:20') ], [ (u'10:00', u'11:20'), (u'13:00', u'14:20'), (u'14:30', u'15:50'),] [ (u'08:30', u'09:20'), (u'10:30', u'11:20')]]
```

Answer (score 4):

`for` statement is missing [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, elm in enumerate(array):
```

But, if you want to sort the list in-place, you don't need to use index. Use [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) instead:

```
for elm in array:                                                              
    elm.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: @The6thSense, Strings like `10:30` cannot be converted to `int`.

Comment: Sorry did not see the actual data now I have a little doubt should not it be sorted according to time than normal strings ? It provides the correct output but is string comparsion enough here ?

Comment: @The6thSense, Strings are sorted according to lexicographical order. `'10:30' < '11:45'`

Comment: @The6thSense: Normal (lexicographic) string sorting will sort these time strings correctly because they are zero-padded. If we had times like `2:30` then there _would_ be problems because eg, `'2:30' > '10:30'` is True.

Comment: @PM2Ring hmm yeah that makes sense :).

Answer (score 1):

When you do `for index, elm in array:`, you're iterating over pairs of objects. On the first loop iteration, `index` is `(u'10:30', u'11:20')` and `elm` is `(u'08:30', u'09:20')`, which isn't what you want (I get `TypeError` when I enter your posted code, not `ValueError`). You can get what you planned with the `enumerate()` function:

```
for index, elm in enumerate(array):
    array[index] = sorted(elm, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: @The6thSense - There's a leading zero, so that's not necessary. If there was no leading zero, a simple `int()` call wouldn't be enough to parse these time strings. Adding a leading zero with string formatting would be easier.

Comment: FWIW, using the `sorted` function when the result is going to replace the original list isn't very efficient. That's because  `sorted` copies the source list to a new list and does an in-place sort of that new list. So in this situation it's much better to simply do an in-place sort directly, using the `.sort()` method.